# warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and ‘%i’ gnu_printf format

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu

I am getting the following warning when compiling some legacy C code on Ubuntu Karmic, using gcc 4.4.1

The warning is:

> src/filename.c:385: warning: '0' flag
>   ignored with precision and ‘%i’
>   gnu_printf format

The snippet which causes the warning to be emitted is:

```
 char     buffer[256] ;
 long     fnum ;
 /* some initialization code here ... */
 sprintf(buffer, "F%03.3i.DTA", (int)fnum);  /* <- warning emitted here */
```

I think I understand the warning, but I would like to check in here to see if I am right, and also the (definite) correct way of resolving this.

Comment: what is your understanding? The correct way to resolve it is obviously to remove the zero.

Comment: my understanding is that there is an incompatibility between the data type and the format specifier (this is most likely due to an attempt to format an integral value with a precision).

Comment: No, it is valid to have a precision for an integral specifier. As the man page states, it is used to give the minimum number of digits used for formatting.

Comment: Can't you just use printf("%0*d", 3, (int)fnum);  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `printf(3)` man page:

```
   0      The value should be zero padded.  For d, i, o, u, x, X, a, A, e,
          E,  f, F, g, and G conversions, the converted value is padded on
          the left with zeros rather than blanks.  If the 0  and  -  flags
          both  appear,  the  0  flag is ignored.  If a precision is given
          with a numeric conversion (d, i, o, u, x, and X), the 0 flag  is
          ignored.  For other conversions, the behavior is undefined.
```

So you can have either a zero fill or a minimum number of digits, but not both.

Comment: sorry but ... how would we pad with zeroes if we don't express the length of the field independently from the length of the value ?

Comment: @sylvanulg: Specifying the precision causes `printf()` to pad it with `0` to fill that length. Just make sure that the precision is greater than or equal to the field width.